# Queue is blocking Main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, queue

I've got a `for` loop for 3 items. Inside the `for` loop, for each item I spawn 15 threads. These all return data back to my GUI, but what happens is the `for` loop executes, all 3 items and run through, and 45 threads are spawned. I'm trying to run through the first item, wait until the 15 threads are done, then run through the second item. I need to do all this without using `join()`.

I figured this could be done through `queue` but have trouble with blocking. When I attempted the following, it never moves on to the second set of 15 threads:

```
while True:
    try:
        data = q.get(False)
    except Query.Empty():
        data = None
```

This stops the blocking problem and keeps my GUI continuously updated with the functions performed in each of the 15 threads, but once they execute, it simply ends and doesn't continue the `for` loop. Here is the loop in question:

```
def thing_1(names):
    def thready():
        print "Hello!"
        q.put("Done")
    for name in names:
        print "Working on " + name
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=thready)
        t1.start()
        # Then put 'while True' here
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved quite easily by breaking the `while True` loop when the number of active threads goes down to 1 (assuming you don't have any other thread active). Try

```
while True:
    try:
        data = q.get(block=False)
    except Query.Empty():
        data = None
    if threading.active_count() == 1:
        break
```

You might instead use the same loop body you have now but change the while condition to

```
while threading.active_count() > 1:
```

Comment: You might also consider adding a small (25ms?) sleep into the while loop to avoid your GUI thread taking up too much CPU time.

Comment: Seems to be a problem getting beyond the `except` portion. If I replace your new `if` statement with something simple like `print "Hello!"`, it doesn't even print.

Comment: Sounds like possibly you have confused indentation in your code, but the example context isn't really big enough to decide. The `while` loop should be at the same level as the `for` above. Check by inserting a `print` call that the `while` loop is actually running as you think it is.

Comment: The `while` is required to be within the `for`, otherwise the problem persists where items 2 and 3 are executed simultaneously. The `Queue.Empty()` doesn't seem to be catching. When I replace with a basic `except Exception as e` the sample `print "Hello!"` works.

Comment: Presumably each iteration of the `for` starts a single thread, and `names` has fifteen entries and is called three times? If you put the `while` inside the `for` it will run each time you start a thread.